# SSL with Virtual Hosts Using SNI

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, sni

I am using RHEL 6, httpd-2.4.10, openssl-1.0.2a and I have setup SNI as explained in http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Everytime I restart apache I get following message:

AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release

Is there anyway to have SNI setup without using NameVirtualHost?

Comment: You've already set it up!

Comment: I have set it up using NameVirtualHost but apache keeps complaining that it will be removed soon. What is the alternative configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Per [NameVirtualHost has no effect](https://serverfault.com/questions/576939/namevirtualhost-has-no-effect) the directive `NameVirtualHost` is no longer needed in newer versions and you can just remove that line from the configuration.